# Why doesn't the AWS CloudWatch metric "RequestCount" show me the total number of requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-elb

I have one AWS load balancer going to one EC2 instance. According to the AWS documentation, and what I would expect it to mean, the CloudWatch metric for RequestCount on the ELB should show total number of requests. However, I get a graph mapped to a scale of 0-1, with 1 being the peak.

Is this correct? This is not useful for me. Is there a way to see the actual number of requests?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, answering my own question for future searchers:

You need to go the *Graph metrics* tab and change the *Statistic* option to **Sum** (thanks *@Dejan Peretin*). I previously had it set to **Average**.

[image]

Comment: Use Sum instead of Sample Count. See here for which stat is the most useful for which metric: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-cloudwatch-metrics.html

Comment: @DejanPeretin Thanks